# Fluent-bit \ Elasticsearch - how to overcome mapping mismatches with dynamic mapping?

Tags: elasticsearch, fluent-bit

We use Fluent-Bit to parse kubernetes container logs and send them to elasticsearch (v7.17.3) cluster. We do not create index mapping, as there are many different deployments developed by different teams, and we don't want the management nightmare of managing different template\mappings (there is just no real consolidated log format anyway).

We are finding that we are missing quite a few log messages from elasticsearch due to error: "tried to parse field as object, but found a concrete value" or "Can't get text on a START_OBJECT" (the latter error is quite odd because it is happens when attempting to write json object into type "keyword")

We tried separating the logs to a "per deployment" index, hoping that each deployment follows a standard structure on it's own, but we discovered that many applications (some are third party vendors) do not always follow a strict log structure within their own application.

We can obviously contact the developers and request a fix- but unfortunately this is not always in our control (third party vendors) nor fail proof (mistakes can happen- we still need the logs)

Is it possible to configure one template that will attempt to parse json up to one specific level of nesting and from there on just convert the values to text?
Or maybe is it possible to rename the key \ convert the value on failure and attempt to reship the record?
Are there any other possible solutions?

Edit:
Found that **fluentd** has a function flatten hash to overcome this issue: https://github.com/uken/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch#hash-flattening maybe there is something similar in fluent-bit?